# Can i avoid the creation of the Django auth.model.User table when using "other authentication sources"?

Tags: django, django-authentication

As the **Django** documentation says about [*Other authentication sources*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources), in order to authenticate against another source, you must implement your own **authentication backend**. Also, They explain that:

> The Django admin system is tightly coupled to the Django User object described at the beginning of this document. For now, the best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each user that exists for your backend (e.g., in your LDAP directory, your external SQL database, etc.)

As i'm not going to use the admin system (i'm assuming they are referencing the admin application) **can i avoid that table replication?**

I was thinking of implementing the *authenticate* and *get_user* methods [as the doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) but that implies the instantiation of the *User* class, so the next question would be: **can the *auth.models.User* class be instantiated without having the actual Django User table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is - yes, it can. Simply set the [managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed) property to False on the User model.

Comment: This gives me resources to elaborate in the idea. Many thanks to you!

Comment: Note this method requires manual modification to the code in `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, it is unlikely to add `managed = False` property by monkeypatching metaclass in the `User`

Answer (score 1):

You should map the user from the external authentication into the `auth.User` object.

Comment: doesn't that implies the existence of the Django auth_user table?

Comment: By implication, yes. You shouldn't avoid it. You probably can, by removing auth from installed apps; but you shouldn't, because every third party app expects it to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `django.contrib.auth` from the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only solution. Really? is the only way? anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you don't want the table to be created? If you write (or use a pre-existing) LDAP [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources), the User objects will be stored in the table, but they won't have any password information stored, and you can easily update fields like email address and name during the authentication process, so you won't create a disconnect between information stored in LDAP and managed in the Django table (i.e., you can continue updating auth information from LDAP, and don't have to worry about *also* updating it in the Django DB).

Comment: What you say is a good advantage of keeping the table. In my case, all the authentication related objects (users, groups, etc) are managed by another system, and i only want to authenticate againts that in my Django project, which will not manage the users. Is for an "intranet" so is likely it will never need the feature "manage users".

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid the table and still have any sort authentication. The "alternative" authentication methods still make use of the `auth_user` table, they just authenticate via another means.